# Node.js mongoose schema validation - when using enum, is it case sensitive?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

when creating a mongoose schema, and using enum in order to validate the values, is it case sensitive?

As in:

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
  animal: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['cat', 'dog']
  }
});
const myModel = db.model('animal', mySchema);

const animal1 = new myModel({
  animal: 'CAT'
});
```

Will animal1 be saved or rejected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose has several inbuilt validators. Strings have enum as one of the validators. So enum creates a validator and checks if the value is given in an array & these are case sensitive so it will throw validation error, so you can use .toLowerCase() while saving the doc.

Answer (score 1):

If only Mongoose had a way of manually validating a document. Oh wait, there is, and it's [even documented](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

```
console.log( animal1.validateSync() );
…
Error: animal validation failed: animal: `CAT` is not a valid enum value for path `animal`.
```